# Python pandas dataframe get value from previous row and groupby Months,year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, python-datetime

I already a group by done with getting previous row values in a data frame.

```
groupby_result = df.groupby([df['DateAssigned'].dt.strftime('%m').rename('Month')]).agg({'count'}).cumsum().reset_index()
```

The above lines give me a result like this

```
 Month   DateAssigned  DateCompleted        
  05        1             0

  06        18            4
```

So the code gets the cumulative values for the months that are only present. I want the cumulative values to be carried forwarded even if a month doesn't have a record for it.

my expected result :

```
Month   DateAssigned   DateCompleted   diff
05            1             0           0
06           18             4           17
07           18             4           0
08           20             4           2
```

4th column diff is to just explain things better

Let me explain my requirement - the 7th month doesn't have any value to it, yet it should get the values from the previous month(6th) and carry forward the value to the 8th month

data frame for reference :

```
DateAssigned DateCompleted month

2020-06-18    2020-06-19  2020-06-18
2020-06-18           NaT  2020-06-18
2020-06-19           NaT  2020-06-19
2020-06-18    2020-06-18  2020-06-18
2020-06-23           NaT  2020-06-23
2020-06-04           NaT  2020-06-04      
2020-06-18           NaT  2020-06-18
2020-06-18    2020-06-18  2020-06-18
2020-06-05           NaT  2020-06-05
2020-06-18    2020-06-18  2020-06-18
2020-06-05           NaT  2020-06-05
2020-06-05           NaT  2020-06-05
2020-06-17           NaT  2020-06-17
2020-06-18           NaT  2020-06-18
2020-06-17           NaT  2020-06-17
2020-06-18           NaT  2020-06-18
2020-06-04           NaT  2020-06-04
2020-06-05           NaT  2020-06-05
```

Comment: can you provide sample data for `df`

Comment: Hello, @NarendraPrasath....i have added the data frame per your request....bare with my aligning abilities!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do, use a proper index to adapt it to your actual dataframe

```
df.groupby(df["DateAssigned"].dt.month.rename("Month")).count().cumsum().reindex([5,6,7,8]).ffill().reset_index()
```

Comment: I tried your solution mate. If I reindex all I get is NaN is all the columns expect months

Comment: @SivakumarTG works fine here after converting the columns to datetime, are you sure you shared an extract of your actual dataframe? it would be great if it would include items from several months so there is a clear outcome you want to reproduce (there is only june at the moment)

Comment: I am extremely sorry brother. Your solution was right, I was the culprit here. Your solution solved my purpose. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try using ffill method. This will Forwardfill the previous values if the values are blank or NaN.

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: Thank you.....like you said fillna is used to fill the values in a certain row or column of a data frame as NaN or zero. I looking for a missing month after groupby. I appreciate your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the difference using 'shift()' with the grouped and counted DFs. The output example is an arbitrary result I created, you can replace it with your own.

```
df["DateAssigned"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateAssigned"])
df["DateCompleted"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DateCompleted"])
df = df.groupby(df["DateAssigned"].dt.month.rename("Month")).count()
df['diff'] = df['DateAssigned']-df['DateAssigned'].shift()

df

DateAssigned    DateCompleted   month   diff
Month               
5       1   0   1   NaN
6       18  4   18  17.0
7       9   2   9   -9.0
8       12  2   12  3.0
```

Comment: That's a really good answer, but how does this work when a certain month doesn't even have any values for it? Anyway, I appreciate your answer here. Thank you

Comment: This code groups them by the months that exist, so you can aggregate them even if you don't have a certain month.

Comment: I understand mate, what I want here is Even if a particular month doesn't have any values, it should get value from the previous month and pass on the values to the coming month. You can refer to my expected result section in question for a note.